# Swift- How to accept multiple (union) types as argument

Tags: swift, swiftui, protocols, type-hinting

Here is the playground to get the idea

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct RectangleStyle {
    public var color: Color? = nil
    public var gradient: LinearGradient? = nil
}


struct DemoView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(
                RectangleStyle(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                        gradient: Gradient(colors: [.red, .blue]), 
                        startPoint: .top, 
                        endPoint: .bottom
                    )
                ).gradient!
            )
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(DemoView())
```

As you can see, it's quite ugly. What I would like, is the ability to construct my `RectangleStyle` with whatever object that implement `ShapeStyle` (the protocol required by the `fill()` method on `Rectangle`) and be able to retrieve this `ShapeStyle` (A `Color` or a `Gradient`, etc...) with a single method.

If I add a `init(style: ShapeStyle)` on my `RectangleStyle`, I get the error `Protocol "ShapeStyle" can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`.

And I get the same error if I try to add a `func getStyle() -> ShapeStyle` on my `RectangleStyle`.

How can I properly handle this case? The idea is just to be able to construct my `RectangleStyle` with any object of type compatible with the required type of `Rectangle.fill()` and have a method to return this object.
Is is possible to let Swift know that if the argument was of type A, the return of a method will be the same type (like in Typescript)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done with generics, like

```
struct RectangleStyle<S: ShapeStyle> {
    private let style: S

    init(_ style: S) {      // << your init !!
        self.style = style
    }

    func getStyle() -> some ShapeStyle { // << your func !!
        self.style
    }
}
```

and now your test:

```
let myStyle = RectangleStyle(LinearGradient(
                    gradient: Gradient(colors: [.red, .blue]),
                    startPoint: .top,
                    endPoint: .bottom
                ))

var body: some View {
    Rectangle()
        .fill(myStyle.getStyle())         // << here !!
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
}
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

[Test code is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestShapeStyleHolder.swift)

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you @Asperi (again), my Swift journey wouldn't be the same without you.